# How to convert babel transpiled code into normal js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-hooks, babeljs

I am using plugin called [babel-plugin-transform-react-class-to-function](https://github.com/remcohaszing/babel-plugin-transform-react-class-to-function)
 for conversion of react class to functional component. It is converting the given input into transpiled babel code but I want the original plain code as specified in the readme of given plugin's github. How can I do that>

Ex : Given input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iInma.png)

Provided output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33l2d.png)

Required output

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Component } from 'react';

export const HelloWorld = ({ className }) => <div className={className}>Hello world!</div>;

HelloWorld.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extra Babel plugin:

- [@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) -  parse JSX syntax

e.g.

`babel.config.json`:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-class-to-function"
  ]
}
```

In:

`index.jsx`:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class HelloWorld extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        className: PropTypes.string,
    };

    render() {
        const { className } = this.props;

        return <div className={className}>Hello world!</div>;
    }
}
```

Command for compiling:

```bash
npx babel ./index.jsx -d ./
```

Out:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const HelloWorld = ({
  className
}) => {
  return <div className={className}>Hello world!</div>;
};
HelloWorld.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string
};
export { HelloWorld };
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"@babel/cli": "^7.22.15",
"@babel/core": "^7.22.17",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.22.5",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-class-to-function": "^1.2.2",
"prop-types": "^15.8.1"
```